# How can I paint a sink hole cover?

Tags: paint, sink

The sink hole cover was copper, but after years of cleaning, the color is wearing off. I'd like it to be the same color in acrylic paint (which I have) as our faucet, which is bronze. Can this be done?

[image: Hole cover - electroplate]

Comment: What do you mean by 'sink hole cover'?

Comment: Hi patton515, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy your time here sharing. Don't forget to visit [tour] and [help] to find out how best to benefit from the site.

Comment: Could you possibly add a picture?

Comment: This 'snap in' sink hole cover (pictured) is electroplated. Can I get a 'nice'?

Comment: @Stan if only edit could be upvoted...

Answer (score 1):

In a word, **Yes**.
 You **can** paint the metal part to match the faucet; but the finish will be cosmetic, and will wear off with cleaning using anything abrasive. It will not last as long as the original metal-plated surface. You will have to re-apply the acrylic cover-up periodically.

You can get a replacement and/or avoid aggressive cleaning of the used surface-treated one.

Painting will be a short-term hack.

Good luck.